# How to Animate Sprites in Gamemaker

Tags: animation, sprite

I would like to make my sprite stand still when not moving and animate when keys are pressed. I have a sprite with 8 images and an object that I have created where I assigned the sprite. I have added a key press and key release command and I have added a section where you can put your own custom code. However when I play the game the sprite is animating right away until I press a key and then he stops animating and moves in a still position. How can I fix this?

```
if image_index = 0
{
image_speed = 0;
}
else
{
image_index = 1;
image_speed = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in what you posted.

So in other words. If your going to do it this way. Why not just use 3 sprites one for stand one for left and one for right?

of if you insist on not doing that then just set image_index to 0 to start so